# Passing off Encrypted Username and Password from Encrypted JSON file within Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, encryption, gnupg, browser-automation

So I am trying to pass off encrypted data from a secrets.json file I have within a specific directory within my git repository that is ignored by the .gitignore file. I installed gpg and was able to actually encrypt the file and also have that ignored within the same directory as I added a `*.gpg` attribute to my `.gitignore` file. However, I don't know how to pass of the encrypted data from within the encrypted JSON file.

My Json file looks like this and is titled `secrets.json`:

```
{
        "user": {
            "name": "username",
            "password": "password"
  }
}
```

When I encrypt that with gpg on a windows based machine I use:

```
gpg --output secrets.gpg --encrypt .\secrets.json
```

This creates an encrypted json file of the `secrets.json` file within that directory. I would like to pass off the encrypted data to the website via Python and Selenium. The code I am trying to use is found at the following [link](https://github.com/Richard-Barrett/ITDataServicesInfra/blob/master/Python/Collegeboard/TSI/collegboard_tsi_export.py):

I have a specific section that will send off the json correctly:

```
import json
with open('secrets.json','r') as f:
      config = json.load(f)
```

But how do I do it with a `secrets.gpg` that has been encrypted?
I don't like having flat files just sitting around within a system without encryption.
With the `gpg` command to make the file, if I cat it out it will look like this:

```
…☻♀♥þÁã/æ#5☺☼ÿPÒÁÑg*af˜…‘o►⌂S.▬qd„huÖÏÜr∟       /QVuÆóë♀*3♠ž%♂ÅB☻jKÓ£+û☻¦~q~FyÎïê ☺↓Dlœ*Mgt#É¤x“gú™Ò´ee2f∟y•š„ãe@' ► 2ì4x↑hpòCž½↔¾I‡[¬Ék—F_¹]£ÂO—A♀„NÉ·/aLÄÆÚ☻òHš<›Eò£z'äÇf◄WÐr¨Cµw.→u…j⌂⌂š¯…kS↕={˜→)s~ŸÊ‡Ä^‰6h•Or>♀#È¿¿Ò"♥ºFEu^F…×f*-Bðüƒü/9
gë›t†wmî7ct§þwv]Úf:`Ì~ñ®+˜š↕¬Þí­↑·O=ç<ýL↕7übV )D→.£×Ð☻»♫à‚ŠÃÇ¶Üÿ³H”X~q” ÀOI0kÌù„¥È½Â↓b)á«¬ñ⌂ÍÄ3ð¿ÀùÁà,‹A→Æ▼X0↑♣Ž↔xE‡ÿ®2Á♥aÃøÚì▲B\WSä♥ú☺dþ8Èµi8{↑(¢ËXác☼éqÍu+ôŒDA↑♣Ÿ¥→¼I1n↨rN¦ÿô0r!"ªÕ*Á‚´¡↨²€ÏXWz*³µún1u(„ÞäÇO:$iÖ(×ÃÍDÒEòp↕²Q☻pé♫6”.‰q¹ý@ÓÒAUägÊÊ#@^GQ☺;-§7™Ð±”­ø›↕V@SºVK☻HãÒ,↓€W²`⌂CºŠYÕZòø®ÄwW
¯/☺Ä¦ëa"³+(ŠM~^TÕ0Ñ↕‼ÈßZV}Q£FEû´ÏuußaæT☻Æ½„Ý?†ñ↑~↕GÎ↓2”Z£däÿÌi`m‹÷ ♂0&Õž#<”#ËZ‰§Ì§µ
☻ˆÜ¬8÷§2µù®ŒËïM×▬òkÊü+‼Í–
```

I realize this is randomized so it might look different for anyone else that will use gpg to reproduce the issue.

Comment: The file is encrypted. Of cause you will have to decrypt it to access the content.

Comment: Is there a way to pass off user credentials with a live decryption process that doesn't output to a file via gpg?

Comment: why encrypting entire file? instead encrypt username and/or password. Then just send secrets.json using python.

Comment: Have you considered a non-proprietary encryption instead of gpg?

Comment: Well the file sits on a windows server, and I don't trust the security of Windows as I do Linux. Furthermore, we have to maintain HIPPA and FERPA compliance, so I am trying to pass off data from an encrypted file v. a non-encrypted file. I did think of just having a ```gpg --decrypt .\secrets.gpg``` command which could save the file to a specific output, and then remove the file as the process ends. I guess that could be a way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found an answer, I just have not been able to figure out how to clean up the file afterwards. But basically you have to create the file from an encrypted file and then remove it. The following allows me to actually decrypt the information into a json file using the subprocess module.

```
#!/bin/python
# ===========================================================
# Created By: Richard Barrett
# Organization: DVISD
# DepartmenT: Data Services
# Purpose: Test Score & 3rd Party Website Data Pull Automation
# Date: 01/20/2020
# ===========================================================

import selenium
import shutil
import xlsxwriter
import os
import unittest
import requests
import subprocess
import getpass
import time 
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from datetime import date

decrypt = "gpg --output secrets_test.json --decrypt secrets.gpg" 
returned_value = subprocess.call(decrypt, shell=True)

import json
with open('secrets_test.json','r') as f:
      config = json.load(f)

### SOME SELENIUM PROCESS ###

# Delete the Unencrypted File
if os.path.exists("secrets_test.json"):
  os.remove("secrets_test.json")
else:
  print("The file does not exist")

browser.quit()
```

It basically decrypts the file and stores it in json output using gpg. I used passwordless encryption, which I know is not secure but it allows me to store the data as encrypted and pass off a decryption process for password and credential pass off in selenium the only issue I have now is removing the file. But I found out how to remove the file with os.remove() function from the `os` module.